How to prove this binomial lower bound?
I have been stuck in this problem for a while and no prolific idea comes up to my mind, could anyone indicate a path to its solution?
$$\begin{pmatrix}n\\k\end{pmatrix}\geq\frac{n^k}{4k!}$$ for $k \leq \sqrt{n}$

https://rjlipton.com/2014/01/15/bounds-on-binomial-coefficents/
